# R import changes binary factors to intervals

Tags: r, import, factors

I have a dataframe which contains several binary variables, labelled as "0" and "1". I converted these to factors in R after initial import, saved the variables as factors using `as.factor()`, and saved the dataframe using `write.csv()`. The next time I imported the saved dataframe, R imported these variables as intervals again.

Is there any way to ensure that these metadata are saved and applied on each import, so that I don't have to apply `as.factor()` to every one of these variables every time I work on the data and for each subset of the data I create?

Comment: You could set `colClasses` in `read.csv`. Or you could use `save` to save the full R object. Or you could add a label to the factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving as an R object solved my problem. Thanks, user20650.

Comment: your welcome - you can click the tick to mark this as answered